# Redmine don't send e-mail, execution expired error

Tags: redmine

I'm having problems using email in redmine. This is my redmine Environment versions:

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                2.4.2.stable
  Ruby version                   1.9.3-p484 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  3.2.16
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               MySQL
SCM:
  Git                            1.9.1
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed
```

I configured the configuration.yml file like this:

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: "smtp.office365.com"
      port: 587
      domain: "mydomain.com.br"
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "user@mydomain.com.br"
      password: "mypassword"

  attachments_storage_path: /home/redmin/Downloads/redmine-2.3.2/files

  autologin_cookie_name:
  autologin_cookie_path:
  autologin_cookie_secure:

  scm_subversion_command: svn
  scm_mercurial_command:
  scm_git_command: /usr/bin/git
  scm_cvs_command:
  scm_bazaar_command:
  scm_darcs_command:

  scm_stderr_log_file:

  database_cipher_key:

  rmagick_font_path:
```

So, i access redmine in browser and click in button "Send Test Email" but i got the following error: `execution expired` after a lot of time loading page.

In my production.log file i got a success message without any error, but e-mail never arrive:

```
Sent email "Redmine test" (30215ms)
  to: target@gmail.com
```

**Edit 1:**
If i change the devlivery_method to ":sendmail" the test works but email never arrives.